# When i run the contract i got below mentioned error

Tags: solidity, truffle-migration

```
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
    at Object.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329221:46)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:39618:25
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:331159:9
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:175492:11
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:314196:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:315621:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70159:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70449:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70604:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70564:24)
```

Comment: Improve your question. Kindly, Show step by step what you have done after that you got this error.

Comment: You didn't put enough info to say something, one possibility is that your contract is too large and you need to adjust the gas amount in your truffle.js settings.